# I'm trying to make an app which play Youtube videos inside the android app using Youtube API but getting an error. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an application which plays youtube videos inside the app created by me but I get an error when I use this library in build.

```
implementation 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:
```

Error is:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:7.0.1 Show in
>   Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

The library I added in the gradle for YoutbeVideoPlaayer

```
 implementation 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:7.0.1'
```

Comment: It is saying the desired library is not found. And you can use youtubeApi for playing youtubes video rather then some third party Api.

Comment: Add full build.gradle file of root level build.gradle & module-level build.gradle in question

Answer (score -2):

The said library has been updated to 10.0.5 from 7.0.1.
Add this

> implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'

Comment: Please don't tell people to upvote you in your answers.